# CharacterEscaper - further optimizable? Bugs?

Tags: java

I have been working on a character escaper for a production server that receives quite a few requests per second (sometimes in the range of 400).

We forward some "query" requests to apache Lucent/SOLR, and I need to escape characters.

Containing also feedback from [programmers-stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212254/optimized-special-character-escaper-vs-matcher-pattern) , the code below is the result.

**Can anyone see any bugs or additional ways to optimize?**

```
String query = "http://This+*is||a&&test(whatever!!!!!!)";
char[] queryCharArray = new char[query.length()*2];
char c;
int length = query.length();
int currentIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    c = query.charAt(i);
    if(mustBeEscaped[c]){        
      if('&'==c || '|'==c){
        if(i+1 < length && query.charAt(i+1) == c){
            queryCharArray[currentIndex++] = '\\'; 
            queryCharArray[currentIndex++] = c; 
            queryCharArray[currentIndex++] = c; 
            i++;
        }
      }    
      else{
        queryCharArray[currentIndex++] = '\\'; 
        queryCharArray[currentIndex++] = c; 
      }     
    }
    else{
        queryCharArray[currentIndex++] = c;     
    }
}

query = new String(queryCharArray,0,currentIndex);

System.out.println("TEST="+query);

private static final boolean[] mustBeEscaped = new boolean[65536];
static{
mustBeEscaped[':']=  //
  for(char c: "\\?+-!(){}[]^\"~*&|".toCharArray()){
     mustBeEscaped[c]=true; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your original version a lot better. If you need this to be faster, then I would suggest to just write it in C.

Comment: Have you profiled your application? Are you sure this method is a bottleneck?

Comment: You can avoid creating a new `queryCharArray` on each call by reusing always the same preallocated 'big enough' one. I am not sure if that would improve the speed.

Comment: @MrSmith42: Only a good idea if there are no threads involved.

Comment: @Bobby: If threads are involved, you can still reuse threadlocal preallocated arrays.

Comment: @MrSmith42: Depends, I think, but true. Depends if the thread is reused or if it is a worker-thread dedicated to one task with only calling this escaping one or two times (think of accepting connections). I had the that one in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I have to be honest and say that this code puts me into WTF-Mode very early on, but that must not be a bad thing. But what took me by surprise is the lack of comments, there are some edge-cases in there I can not make out why they're the way they're.

On the latter, changing, suggestions I did only perform minor profiling by simply running it in a loop with 1 million iterations and seeing if the time differs by much.

---

Rule of thumb: Never roll your own security!

---

Your indentation/brace-style is a mess. Java normally uses a modified K&R-Style, with the opening brace on the same line.

```
function test() {
    if (condition) {
        // Stuff
    } else {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

You should fix that first.

---

Some of your names can be improved. F.e. `queryCharArray` might be better named `escapedQuery`.

---

You might want to extract all hard coded chars at least into static final variables for readability.

---

Your loop-beginning can be changed to:

```
char[] queryCharArray = new char[query.length() * 2];
int currentIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
        char c = query.charAt(i);
```

This improves readability by a lot.

---

Your loop can be optimized to this:

```
char c = query.charAt(i);
if (mustBeEscaped[c]) {
    queryCharArray[currentIndex++] = '\\';
    if ('&' == c || '|' == c) {
        if (i + 1 < query.length() && query.charAt(i + 1) == c) {
            queryCharArray[currentIndex++] = c;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
queryCharArray[currentIndex++] = c;
```

This removes unnecessary else-blocks.

---

```
if ('&' == c || '|' == c) {
    if (i + 1 < query.length() && query.charAt(i + 1) == c) {
```

You should leave a comment here explaining why these characters are special. Extracting them into another array might be a good idea.

```
if (skipNextOccurence[c]) {
```

---

Putting all this together (and renaming the constants to fit the Java naming conventions), I ended up with this in my tests:

```
private static final boolean[] MUST_BE_ESCAPED = new boolean[65536];
private static final boolean[] SKIP_NEXT_OCCURENCE = new boolean[65536];
private static final char ESCAPE_CHARACTER = '\\';

static {
    for (char c : "\\?+-!(){}[]^\"~*&|".toCharArray()) {
        MUST_BE_ESCAPED[c] = true;
    }
    for (char c : "&|".toCharArray()) {
        SKIP_NEXT_OCCURENCE[c] = true;
    }
}

private static String escape(String query) {
    char[] escapedQuery = new char[query.length() * 2];
    int currentIndex = 0;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < query.length(); idx++) {
        char c = query.charAt(idx);

        if (MUST_BE_ESCAPED[c]) {
            escapedQuery[currentIndex++] = ESCAPE_CHARACTER;

            if (SKIP_NEXT_OCCURENCE[c]) {
                // Check if the next char is the same, and if yes add it to
                // the escapedQuery and make sure that it is skipped.
                if (idx + 1 < query.length() && query.charAt(idx + 1) == c) {
                    escapedQuery[currentIndex++] = c;
                    idx++;
                }
            }
        }

        escapedQuery[currentIndex++] = c;
    }

    return new String(escapedQuery, 0, currentIndex);
}
```

---

To elaborate on the possibilities to use a StringBuilder, or a Set, or pretty much everything else I tried to come up with which looked more readable...damn that thing is fast! Even using a StringBuilder slowed it down considerably. So as long as you're aware that you are, a little bit at least, abusing memory with that 65k array (which will end up as 65k * 8Byte on most platforms) it's fine with me.

Also don't forget that you allocate twice the amount of whatever is passed into this function. So if somebody feels funny and passes a 1Mb query into that, it will *at least* consume 3Mb (1+1*2) on it's way. That is, if the JVM is not smarter then I think and does not allocate all that at once.

Just use more comments and JavaDoc.

Comment: +1 Nice comments overall.  Just some further style suggestions.  When you have a constant declared as `static final`, it's generally named in `CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORE_SPACES`.  So `escapeCharacter` might be renamed `ESCAPE_CHARACTER`.  I might also make these `String` literals into actual constants, just for readability, but that's entirely subjective (`"\\?+-!(){}[]^\"~*&|".toCharArray()`).  Really elegant ideas with the two huge `boolean[]`s though.  Very clever. :)

Comment: @JeffGohlke: Good call! I fall for that one *every single time*. And of course feel free to add your own answer, even if just has one or two points, it counts.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I really doubt that this function is your performance bottleneck.  Compared to the act of searching through your document repository, the work involved in escaping the query string is surely negligible!

Second, I think there is a bug.  Is your intention to let `&&` and `||` pass through unescaped to the output, while prefixing single `&` or `|` with a backslash?  If so, you should note your intentions in a comment.  As written, your code would produce no output corresponding to a solitary `&` or `|` in the input.

By the way, I would consider that hybrid treatment of the query string as a red flag.  Is your input supposed to contain literal search terms?  Or a Lucene/SOLR query?  Why are you trying to create a dumbed-down search language that only supports `&&` and `||` but not the other features of the Lucene/SOLR language?  Even in the best case, it would still lead to a weird user experience.

Third, it's wasteful to use a 65336-element array to detect 17 special characters.  That's 64 kiB, or 8 kiB assuming super-efficient packing.  Wasteful memory usage could also hurt performance by creating pressure on the cache.  The use of a lookup table is particularly deplorable here since you still have special cases  for `&&` and `||` that have to be hard-coded in the logic anyway.  For all these ills, I recommend using a `switch` statement instead, which should be quite efficient.

Fourth, I recommend using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `char[]`, because that's exactly what it's meant for.

Here's how I would write it…

```
public static String escapeLuceneQuery(String query) {
    int len = query.length();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(2 * len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = query.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
          case '&':  case '|':
            if (i + 1 < len && query.charAt(i + 1) == c) {
                // Special case: pass through && and || to the output
                result.append(c).append(c);
                i++;
                break;
            }
            // Solitary & or |.  Flow through...
          case '\\': case '?':  case '+':  case '-':  case '!':
          case '(':  case ')':  case '{':  case '}':
          case '[':  case ']':  case '^':  case '"':
          case '~':  case '*':
            result.append('\\');
            // Flow through...
          default:
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: That's not correct, `&&` should become `\&&` according to OPs code. Except if I misread that part.

Comment: @Bobby I wrote my solution the way as OP probably intended, rather than bug-compatible with OP's code.

Comment: I doubt that this implementation is faster. But only profiling can proof that. It also looks a lot like the implementation before the optimization posted on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/212254/optimized-special-character-escaper-vs-matcher-pattern

Comment: @MrSmith42: Oh, so you were the mad mind that came up with that 65k-bool-array. The idea is awesome, mad, but awesome.

Comment: @Bobby: *speed* was the goal, memory was not a limitation. And if the problem can be reduced to ASCII, an array of size 128 would be sufficient.